# Подстроить изображение под <div> блок

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такой вот блок:

```css
.inner {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.date {
  font-family: Courier New, monospace;
  color: #424242;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
}

hr {
  color: red;
  /* Цвет линии для остальных браузеров */
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 0;
  height: 2px;
}

.header {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <div class="header">Заголовок</div>
  <span class="date">25/07/2017</span><br>
  <hr>
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```

И внизу статьи все оставшееся место в блоке должно занимать изображение. Если заголовка одна строчка, то я делаю это таким кодом:

```css
.news_img {
  background: url(../images/test.jpg) no-repeat;
  height: 354px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

И получается полное заполнение, но если название заголовка занимает 2 строчки, то изображение едет вниз. Как можно сделать так, чтобы изображение уменьшалось под оставшееся место? Проценты не прокатывают, потому что тогда изображение подстаивается под всю высоту блока, без учета заголовка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задайте для `.inner {overflow:hidden}` - тогда картинка не будет выезжать за пределы блока.

```css
.inner {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.date {
  font-family: Courier New, monospace;
  color: #424242;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

hr {
  color: red;
  /* Цвет линии для остальных браузеров */
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 0;
  height: 2px;
}

.header {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_large/republic_of_singapore_air_force_17480.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <div class="header">Заголовок Заголовок Заголовок Заголовок </div>
  <span class="date">25/07/2017</span><br>
  <hr>
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```